# Applying Custom Title bar to the whole Application without changing each Activity?

Tags: android, titlebar

Now I have my nifty custom title bar in its own XML layout file and I've got my custom theme and style XML files.    From my Activity class I can invoke it and it looks great.

Problem is my app has 14 Activities, each with their associated layout file.    If I want to see the same title bar appear across my app, i.e., in all my Activities, the two main strategies I've seen are:

1. Put a an `<include layout="@layout/my_title_bar" />` for my title bar in every layout file

...or...

1. Change all my Activity classes to derive from some common Activity that invokes the new title bar

Before I go off and do one of these I just want to make sure there's no more "centralized' way of doing it, like, say, in the manifest.    There's no need to declare the default title bar in every activity, and it doesn't seem right to have to make separate changes for each activity for an app-wide feature like a custom title bar.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Why not extend from the Application class?

Comment: @Falmarri:  Action Bar and Title Bar are not the same.   I'm running on Gingerbread.

Comment: Extending the Application class is an intriguing idea.   Wouldn't fullscreen Activities just overwrite it?   I've seen lots of people ask how to apply a custom titlebar to the whole app, but I don't recall ever seeing this proposed.

Comment: Hmmm... good point... the alternative is to specify the theme in the `application` tag in the manifest, i.e. `android:theme="@style/myStyle"` as part of the tag...

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ever find a solution to this?